# ink! tutorial: substrate-contracts-node build fails

Tags: ink, tutorials

I am making my way through the ink! "First Contract" tutorial:
https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/ink-workshop/pt1/

When trying to download the precompiled node:

```
cargo install contracts-node --git https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git --tag <latest-tag> --force --locked
```

I get the following errors:

```
error[E0046]: not all trait items implemented, missing: `MaxCodeLen`, `RelaxedMaxCodeLen`
     --> /Users/keeganquigley/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-contracts-node-cf7c16677784d274/254342f/runtime/src/lib.rs:302:1
      |
  302 | impl pallet_contracts::Config for Runtime {
      | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ missing `MaxCodeLen`, `RelaxedMaxCodeLen` in implementation
      |
      = help: implement the missing item: `type MaxCodeLen = Type;`
      = help: implement the missing item: `type RelaxedMaxCodeLen = Type;`

  error[E0609]: no field `code_len` on type `Limits`
     --> /Users/keeganquigley/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-contracts-node-cf7c16677784d274/254342f/runtime/src/lib.rs:297:19
      |
  297 |         schedule.limits.code_len = 256 * 1024;
      |                         ^^^^^^^^ unknown field
      |
      = note: available fields are: `event_topics`, `stack_height`, `globals`, `parameters`, `memory_pages` ... and 5 others
```

Regardless of what release I use. substrate-node-template compiles fine and I can run a local node - any ideas on what I am missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this is a bug in `cargo install --git <URL> --locked` which ignores the `--locked` part and updates the substrate dependencies. You can workaround this by cloning the `substrate-contracts-node` and running the following command there:

```
git checkout <LATEST_TAG>
cargo install --path ./node/ --locked
```

For release v0.15.1`:

```
git clone https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git
cd substrate-contracts-node
git checkout v0.15.1
cargo install --path ./node/ --locked
```

Comment: Thanks all, that worked! Got it up and running.